# Equivalent of SETEX for GET and TTL

Tags: redis, redis-py

`SETEX` is a useful Redis command whereby one can set the `value` and `expiry` of a key in a single, atomic operation.

Is there an equivalent operation that atomically enables a person to retrieve the key's `value` and `ttl`? I know I can do it in a pipeline as well, but I'm asking whether something elegant like `SETEX` exists. If it matters, I'm using Redis 2.8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no such command. However, you can wrap `GET` and `TTL` into a Lua script, to get both value and ttl in a single atomic call.

Also, you **CANNOT** achieve that with pipeline. Because Redis **DOES NOT** guarantee that commands in pipeline are running atomically.

Comment: I'm curious: is there any advantage of using a `pipeline` here at all ?

Comment: @HassanBaig I don't see any advantage. In this case, Lua scripting is better.

Comment: How about that if the pipeline fails, both calls fail. So in that regard, it's like wrapping it into a single transaction - which either goes through, or doesn't in its entirety?

Comment: NO, that's **NOT** transaction. With pipeline, there might be other commands between `GET`, and `TTL`. Suppose, Redis runs `GET` successfully, and the current ttl is `100`, however, it might run other calls for `10` seconds before it runs `TTL`. So the client will get `90` as ttl. However, with transaction, e.g. Lua scripting, there're NO other commands between `GET` and `TTL`. So the client will always get `100` as ttl.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `MULTI/EXEC` to make sure some commands being in a transaction. pipeline just save the network transport time(rtt), because it will send the request in a batch and recieve reply in a batch also.

You could refer [Redis Transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) and [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) for more details.